# I need to create separate file for all the constants of my project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variables

In my project I have a requirement to create separate file for all constants that i am using in separate classes in the same project.

I seen some examples but they are saying about creating in '.h' file and again they are implementing them in '.m' files. But i need only '.h'file to create all constants and i have to use all those constants by importing that '.h' file in every class of my project.

Comment: Do you mean regular constants definde in #define statments? If so, why don't you just define them in any *.h file, let's say "constants.h" and then include it in every *.m file where you need to make use of the constants? That's the way I do with real constants.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]
ADD a new file.

- Right click on the file inspector
- choose New File
- The pop up window select ios>C and C++>HeaderFile[Figure]
- Give name Constants
- Add `#define OK @"OK"`
- Go to View Controller include file in header     `#import "Constants.h"`
  **OR** Define in pch file ,so that all View controllers can access the file
- In viewDidLoad     `NSLog(@"%@",OK);`

Answer (score 1):

You can create .h file and use #define to create constants and then include your file to prefix file of your project. Though I prefer to use extern constants which you declare in .h file and define in .m file. This help to track possible warnings in your code at compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much answered your own question, to the point where I'm not sure exactly what you're asking - you can just create a header file (.h) with your constants, and import it into your other classes. You don't need to create a corresponding implementation (.m) file. If you're using your constants throughout your code you could import them in your prefix header and have them automatically available.